# Eternal uncreated things besides God

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion, plato

There is a big debate in the Philosophy of Rellgion as to whether or not there are things that are uncreated eternal things besides God, like abstract objects.

Some say that claiming there are uncreated, eternal things besides God is tantamount to polytheism. Why?

Comment: See [IEP, Abstract Objects as Uncreated](https://iep.utm.edu/pla-thei/#SH4b):"*if abstract objects exist a se, then God is not unique, exists alongside abstract objects and, exists as one being among many others existing by their own nature. This problem has been designated as the uniqueness problem.*"

Comment: But why do you think that the only "feature" of God is to be uncreated?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the only feature, just a characteristic feature. God being the only necessary being is used in the cosmological argument, for example, some also see abstract competitors as undermining God's status as the moral law-giver along the lines of the [Euthyphro dilemma](https://iep.utm.edu/divine-c/#H3), and, by implication, undermining his supreme metaphysical position and omnipotence.

Comment: Not polytheism. You might like to research the two ancient Indian philosophical traditions known as Samkhaya and Yoga (the ancient school and not the physical exercises or the meditation techniques commonly called such). See here https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey and 'A History of Indian Philosophy' here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism